# Setting NSForegroundColorAttributeName on an attributed string shifts the text down on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm using attributed strings in my iOS app to give the text some style:

```
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:              [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway" size:12],
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName:   [UIColor lightGreyTextColor]};

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:titleAttributes];
```

The problem is that on iOS 6, the text is not vertically centered in the `UILabel` anymore. On iOS 7 it's fine.

I found that when I remove the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` attribute then it's correctly centered but the text is black

Does anyone know a way to fix that? Is it a bug in iOS or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `UITextAttributeTextColor` instead of `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

Seems to be the same issue, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863972/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crashes-because-of-global-appearance-properties-on-i).

Comment: UITextAttributeTextColor is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Make sure you put the line of code that centers the text after you add the attributes to the label

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_IS_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
    [self.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:2 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```