# MFMailComposeViewController Crashes because of Global Appearance Properties on iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiappearance

I am getting the following crash when I present a `MFMailComposeViewController`:

```
2013-11-08 11:04:05.963 <redacted>[7108:1603] *** Assertion failure in NSDictionary *_UIRecordArgumentOfInvocationAtIndex(NSInvocation *, NSUInteger, BOOL)(), /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIAppearance.m:1118
2013-11-08 11:04:06.032 <redacted>[7108:1603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unknown key, "NSColor" in title text attributes dictionary'
```

I've tracked it down to the following appearance setting in my AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
            @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Commenting that line out does the trick, but ruins the rest of the app, so I tried specifically setting the titleTextAttributes to an empty dictionary for the `MFMailComposeViewController`:

**Attempt #1**

```
        [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:
            NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"), nil]
            setTitleTextAttributes:@{ }];
```

That results in the same crash. And

```
        [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:
            NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"), nil]
            setTitleTextAttributes:nil];
```

also results in the same crash.

**Attempt #2**

I noticed that `MFMailComposeViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, so maybe the global appearance settings are localized to UIViewControllers *inside* a UINavigationController. I put together some code to figure out what view controllers are inside the MFMailComposeViewController:

```
        for (UIViewController *viewController in mailViewController.viewControllers) {
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
        }
```

Which results in the output:

```
2013-11-08 11:04:05.936 <redacted>[7108:907] MFMailComposeInternalViewController
```

So I tried *(even though it's bad practice to rely on Apple's private view controllers)*:

```
        [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:
            NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"), nil]
            setTitleTextAttributes:@{ }];
```

And

```
        [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:
            NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"), nil]
            setTitleTextAttributes:nil];
```

But that still results in the same crash!

**Attempt #3**

```
        // right before instantiating the MFMailComposeViewController
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ }];
```

And

```
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:nil];
```

Then restoring the global appearance properties in the completion block of `dismissViewController:animated:completion:`

However, this approach didn't work either. Does anyone know how to set titleTextAttributes on the global `UINavigationBar` appearance without crashing MFMailComposeViewController?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using `UITextAttributeTextColor` instead of `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

Comment: Man, I can't believe it was something this dumb. This is one of those enums that keeps going back and forth through the iOS releases; I can't keep it straight in my head.

Comment: Oh dear Lord, thank you Jonathan!! 20 person-hours of debugging solved with this.

Comment: I'd like to add that the same problem appears with QLPreviewController. It crashes when using UIAppearance and NSForegroundColorAttributeName. Using the now deprecated UITextAttributeTextColor works fine.

Comment: my problem seemed to be a combination of this and changing `NSFontAttributeName` to `UITextAttributeFont` as well

Comment: It seems iOS 8 bug, but no luck even with the above solution.

Comment: The compiler will not allow this in iOS8.

Answer (score 2):

Just extends UINavigationController class

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

replace all your UINavigationController class with the new subclass
and [appearanceWhenContainedIn:] in your app delegate

```
[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationController class], nil].titleTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] };
```

after that your app will not crash.

Comment: I prefer this solution since it is more architecturally correct.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to solve this was to create `[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:] setTitleTextAttributes:]` for each of my `UIViewControllers`. Luckily this was fairly simple, because all of my custom view controllers come from 4 view controller subclasses.

Edit: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19867457/953105) because I'm dumb.

Comment: did you file a bug with apple?