# MFMailComposerVIewController CRASH in ios6 but work fine in ios7?

Tags: ios7, crash, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Kindly sort this out , Thanks.

SCENARIO: In SDK-7 On button click I am able to open MFMailComposerVC with its delegate method and all thing works fine. But as I changed simulator to 6.1/6.0 it crashs on button click.

ERROR LOG:

```
*** Assertion failure in NSDictionary *_UIRecordArgumentOfInvocationAtIndex(NSInvocation  *, NSUInteger, BOOL)(), /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIAppearance.m:1118

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unknown key, "NSColor" in title text attributes dictionary'
```

SOLUTION: I found and implement solutions of following link and have did some experimental code but always crash,
[MFMailComposeViewController Crashes because of Global Appearance Properties on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863972/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crashes-because-of-global-appearance-properties-on-i)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFMailComposeViewController Crashes because of Global Appearance Properties on iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863972/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crashes-because-of-global-appearance-properties-on-i)

Comment: hey have you got solution for this. I am facing same problem. Its not duplicate as mentioned in above comment