# AdBannerView crashes app when it is clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, iad, adbannerview

I have an Ad on my app which, before when you clicked on it, would load up the standard test ad screen though recently when I have done this it come back with this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in NSDictionary *_UIRecordArgumentOfInvocationAtIndex(NSInvocation *, NSUInteger, BOOL)(), /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIAppearance.m:1118
```

This doesn't seemed to have happened to anyone else from a google

I am testing on ios 6 which is where the bug happens and works fine on IOS 7

Comment: Is this in iOS 7.1? The underscore in front of the function name suggests that it might be an internal Apple bug.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863972/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crashes-because-of-global-appearance-properties-on-i)? It seems to be related.

Comment: @lootsch no I had not seen this question thank you for pointing it out for me as it works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by a global appearance setting.
There is a similar error cause by this setting as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863972/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crashes-because-of-global-appearance-properties-on-i):

Use `UITextAttributeTextColor` instead of `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.