# MFMailComposeViewController crashes when trying to send email from iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am creating a `Note` kind of application using `ARC`, where user can share his notes via Email.  My problem is when I present a `MFMailComposeViewController` then app is crashing with the below error :

```
*** Assertion failure in NSDictionary *_UIRecordArgumentOfInvocationAtIndex(NSInvocation *, NSUInteger, BOOL)(), /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIAppearance.m:1118

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unknown key, "NSColor" in title text attributes dictionary'
```

The code is as follows:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *strSubject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A Note from %@", [prefs stringForKey:@"strAppTitle"]];

            [picker setSubject:strSubject];

            NSString *emailBody = strNoteText;
            [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

I have implemented the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol. Can you please give me any suggestion that where i am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863972/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crashes-because-of-global-appearance-properties-on-i) post?

Comment: Can you add some more code related to above things?

Answer (score 1):

you have given 'strNoteText' as MessageBody, check whether it is null or not

Comment: strNoteText is not null. The error was i have mentioned [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]; in my code. Thanks